# Three.js plane geometry border around texture

Tags: webgl, three.js

I am building a 3D image viewer which has Three.JS plane geometries as placeholders with the images as their textures.

Now I want to add a black border around the image. The only way I have found yet to implement this is to add a new black plane geometry behind the image to be displayed. But this required whole-sale changes to my framework which I want to avoid.

WebGL's texture loading function gl.texImage2D has a parameter for border. But I couldn't find this exposed anywhere through Three.js and doubt that it even works the way I think it does.

Is there an easier way to add borders around textures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a temporary regular 2D canvas to render your image and apply any kind of editing/effects there, like paint borders and such. Then use that canvas image as a texture. Might be a bit of work, but you will gain a lot of flexibility styling your borders and other stuff.

I'm not near my dev machine and won't be for a couple of days, so I can't look up an example of my own. This issue contains some code to get you started: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/868

Comment: You are right, but I am going ahead with adding the border as a separate object. I figured this might be less performance intensive than editing every texture (especially since I sometimes need a border and sometimes don't). Thanks!